# PXE installation from VM to another VM

Tags: rhel, virtual-machine, qemu, pxe, virt-manager

I'm trying to do a PXE installation from a VM to another VM. At the host, I'm using RHEL. I created a VM (**srv-inst**) with RHEL using `virt-manager`. The network is the default (NAT) and it is isolated. This is important, because I can't connect the VMs to the network atm.

At the VM (**srv-inst**) I configured the tftp

```
service tftp
{
    socket_type              = dgram
    protocol                 = udp
    wait                     = yes
    server                   = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
    server_args              = -s /tftpboot
    disable                  = no
    pe_source                = 11
    cps                      = 100 2
    flags                    = IPv4
}
```

And configure the `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`.

```
allow bootp;
allow booting;
deny unknown-clients;
option ip-fowarding false;
option mask-supplier false;
default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 604800;
option time-off-set -18000;

subnet 192.168.122.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.122.2 192.168.122.254;
    filename "/pxelinux.0";
    next-server 192.168.122.2;
    interface;
}

host srvinst {
    hardware Ethernet 52:54:00:b9:89:a1;
    fixed-address 192.168.122.2;
    option host-name "srvinst";
}
```

And changed the default network configuration `/etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/default.xml`, following [pxe-setup](https://andreasmarschke.wordpress.com/2012/11/04/pxe-setup-with-libvirt-and-kvm/).

```
<network>
    <name>default</name>
    <bridge name="virbr0" />
    <forward/>
    <ip address="192.168.122.1" netmask="255.255.255.0">
        <tftp root="/tftpboot"/> 
        <dhcp>
            <range start="192.168.122.2" end="192.168.122.254" />
            <host mac='52:54:00:53:19:33' name='srvinst' ip='192.168.122.2'/>
            <host mac='52:54:00:64:61:c9' name='vm1' ip='192.168.122.3'/>
            <bootp file="pxelinux.0"/>
        </dhcp>
    </ip>
</network>
```

When I create another VM, to boot on PXE, it does not find the **srv-inst**.

Any clue?

Comment: Are you sure you defined in DHCP the IP address (not the DNS name) with the `next-server` directive? Why do you think it does not find srv-inst? Please add to the question.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I edited and put some the configs I did. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, If I miss something or did something wrong.

Comment: your next server should not be 192.168.168.2 in the subnet declaration

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro sorry, i wrote wrong... now the next-server is the correct IP. It is the IP in the VM srv-inst.